# Multidimensional array remove inner array key based on condition

Tags: php

I have a array which i want to remove the first and second array from the array since status

is blank for first and second array .

The output should be 
array([0]=> array (
                [A] => 300000
                [B] => jill
        [status]=> "something"
    )
    )

any ideas to proceed?

```
array(
        [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => 100000
            [B] => jjohn
    [status]=>
)

[1] => Array
        (
            [A] => 200000
            [B] => jim
    [status]=>
)
[2] => Array
        (
            [A] => 300000
            [B] => jill
    [status]=> "something"
)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function (array $i) { return $i['status']; });
```

Comment: I need to check whether status is blank

Comment: @mark If `'status'` is an empty string or `null` or `false` or anything else that evaluates to `false`, this does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This function checks if `(bool)$item['status']` is evaluated as **True**, except
string `'0'`.

Function:

```
function ($item) {
    return isset($item['status']) && ($item['status'] || is_string($item['status']));
}
```

Test Code:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'Empty String',
        'status' => '',
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'String Zero',
        'status' => '0',
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'Integer Zero',
        'status' => 0,
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'Bool False',
        'status' => false,
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'NULL',
        'status' => null,
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'Undefined',
    ),
);

$array = array_values(array_filter($array, function ($item) {
    return isset($item['status']) && ($item['status'] || is_string($item['status']));
}));

var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(11) "String Zero"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```